# How can I start Camera on the UI thread without screen freeze?

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm using ZXingScannerView on android to scan qr code.
It works fine, but I want a button that opens/closes the preview and starts/stopts the scanning.
My only problem is, that when I call `scannerView.startcamera(camId);` the screen freezes for half a second until the camera starts. This is really a problem for me, because there is a continuous animation on the screen, which stops (freezes) for a little bit, until the camera starts.

```
    private ZXingScannerView scannerView;
    qrScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( View view ) {

                if ( scannerView != null ) {

                            scannerView.stopCamera();
                            scannerView.stopCameraPreview();
                            scannerView = null;

                } else {

                            scannerView = new ZXingScannerView(MainActivity.this);
                            (( FrameLayout ) findViewById(R.id.scanner_view_container)).addView(scannerView);
                            scannerView.setResultHandler(MainActivity.this);
                            scannerView.setAutoFocus(true);
                            scannerView.startCamera(camId); // this is the only line that causes the 0.5 sec screen freeze. If I comment this out, there is no freezing (but obviously there is no camera preview)
                }
            }
        }
```

How can I start the camera without screen freeze?
It can be started only on the UI thread...

Comment: We need to see more of your code

Comment: I added the code to the question  :)

Comment: Does the [sample code](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner) or [full sample project](https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner/tree/master/zxing-sample) also freeze up for you?  They seem to call `startCamera` in `onResume` so I'm wondering if that's the key.

Comment: They are using a full-screen example, so you don't notice the little freeze on the start (that's why they start it on the `onResume()`).  
I want to be able to turn on/off the reading/preview. 
But I even noticed that this 0.5 sec screen freezing occures just because there is a continuously moving animation on the screen, next to the camera preview. 
This is a mid-range phone, there is no freezing on a high-end device. So maybe there is no solution for that one....  :/

Comment: By the way, the `startCamera()` starts using the camera, and I dont want the camera running all the time (even if I'm not displaying the preview image).

Comment: One possible solution is to move the camera code into a fragment and have it manage everything to do with the camera.  I suspect it wouldn't help but I'd give it a shot.  And failing that, I'd probably just change my animation so that it didn't make the freeze so obvious :-) .